# How to call a function on every route change in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

My module.ts,

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule,Router }   from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent }  from './crud/app.component';
import { Profile }  from './profile/profile';
import { Mainapp }  from './demo.app';
import { Navbar }  from './header/header';
// import {ToasterModule, ToasterService} from 'angular2-toaster';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
@NgModule({

  imports:      [ BrowserModule,FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule ,
  RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component:AppComponent},
      { path: 'login', component:AppComponent},
      { path: 'profile', component:Profile}
    ]) ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent,Mainapp,Navbar,Profile ],
  bootstrap:    [ Mainapp ]
})
export class AppModule { 

}
```

Here i want to call a function from main.ts on every route change and how can i do that.Can anyone please help me.Thanks.
My mainapp.ts,

```
    export class Mainapp {

    showBeforeLogin:any = true;
    showAfterLogin:any;
    constructor( public router: Router) {
     this.changeOfRoutes();

     }
     changeOfRoutes(){
      if(this.router.url === '/'){
         this.showAfterLogin = true;
      }
     }
}
```

I want to call this changeofRoutes() for every route change and how can i do that?Can anyone please help me.

Comment: it is not advisable, what your are going to do in that method

Comment: may be this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/33548895/2036977

Answer (score 75, accepted):

you can call `activate` method from main `router-outlet` like this

```
<router-outlet  (activate)="changeOfRoutes()"></router-outlet>
```

which will call every  time when route will change.

## Update -

Another way to achieve the same is to subscribe to the router events even you can filter them out on the basis of navigation state may be start and end or so, for example -

```
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
  
  @Component({...})
  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.router.events.subscribe((ev) => {
      if (ev instanceof NavigationEnd) { /* Your code goes here on every router change */}
    });
  }
```

Comment: Hi pradeep,its worked greately but its not getting called when I click on back button in my browser.

Comment: i have't tested this so far, so can't say anything

Comment: Ok but your answer help me a lot.Thanks.

Comment: Hey Pradeep,can you answer my question?

Comment: It is working for browser back button also. I have tested this in chrome, mozilla and IE @Daniel

Comment: @Daniel Yes sure, what's your question!

Comment: what if I have multiple outlets ?

Comment: @KishanOza check my updated answer for another way to test.

Answer (score 6):

You can subscribe to the `NavigationEnd` event of router, and retrieve the URL with `urlAfterRedirects` method.

- I strongly recommend you to use the `urlAfterRedirects`, because it seems that you need to `showAfterLogin` conditionally.
- Let's say, you're redirecting `/test-page` to `/`; and you rely on `router.url`. In that case the app will already be redirected to `/` but `router.url` would return `/test-page` and here the **issue** comes (`'/test-page' != '/'`).

Simply, make the following changes in your constructor:

```
export class Mainapp {
    showBeforeLogin:any = true;
    showAfterLogin:any;

    constructor(public router: Router) {
        this.changeOfRoutes();

        this.router.events
            .filter(event => (event instanceof NavigationEnd))
                .subscribe((routeData: any) => {
                    if(routeData.urlAfterRedirects === '/') {
                        this.showAfterLogin = true;
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: the `filter` method depends on `rxjs`. Simply, `import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';` add this import at the beginning of your TS file, should work without a problem.

Answer (score 5):

You can call directive in Routes like below:

```
{ path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent , canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
```

Your AuthGuard component is like below where you put your code:

**auth.guard.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, 
RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

constructor(private router: Router) { }

canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) 
{
    if (localStorage.getItem('currentUser')) {
        // logged in so return true
        return true;
    }

    // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
    this.router.navigate(['/home'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: 
 state.url }});
    return false;
  }
 }
```

You should import AuthGuard component in app.module.ts file and should provide in providers:

**app.module.ts:**

```
......... Your code.......... 
import { AuthGuard } from './_guards/index';
..........Your code..............
  providers: [
    AuthGuard,
    ........
],
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer:[NgRx Router](https://medium.com/@amcdnl/angular-routing-data-with-ngrx-effects-1cda1bd5e579)

Catch all 'Go' actions in ngrx effects to do things just **before** the route changes, or in the reducer of this action to call a function **after** the route changes.