# Angular ngOnit () {} is not working as expected

Tags: angular, angular8

I am new to Angular and I am working angular8. 
I have a component "header" which has some menu with some category. After clicking the category below header component, all products should use API.
The problem is after first click ngOnIt method is triggering as expected but when I choose another category nothing happens.

**Header.component.html**

```
<ul>
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link text-white" (click)="movetolist(4)">FITNESS &
                      SUPPLIMENTS</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link text-white" (click)="movetolist(5)">HEALTH CONDITIONS</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link text-white" (click)="movetolist(6)">HEALTHCARE DEVICES</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link text-white" (click)="movetolist(9)">PERSONAL CARE</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link text-white" (click)="getMedicine(8,'BABY PRODUCT')">BABY PRODUCT</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

**Header.component.ts**

```
movetolist(id) {
  console.log(id);
  this.rout.navigate(['/medicines', id]);
}
```

**List.component.html**

```
<app-header></app-header>

<div class="row listpage">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3" *ngFor="let product of ayurvedic" (click)="movetodetails(product.id)">
    <div class="box" align="center">
      <h6 style="text-align: right">ADD</h6>
      <a>
        <img src="{{product.medicine_photo}}" class="img-fluid">

        <div style="color: none">
          {{product.medicine_name}}</div>
        <div>
          MRP: &#8377;{{product.medicine_price}}</div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**List.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {

this.id = this.routs.snapshot.paramMap.get("id");
console.log(this.id);
    this.service.categories(this.id, this.from, this.to).subscribe(res => {
      if (res['status'] == 1) {
        this.ayurvedic = res['data'];
        console.log(this.ayurvedic);
     }
  });
}
```

**App.routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'medicines/:id', component: ListComponent},
];
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 : Call method/ngoninit when parameter of route changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41300793/angular2-call-method-ngoninit-when-parameter-of-route-changes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

subscribe `route.params`

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';


export class ListComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute
    ) { }

    ngOnInit(){
        this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
            console.log(params.get('id'));    
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add ActivatedRoute service in your constructor:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
...
}
```

and then use:

```
route.params
```

Answer (score 0):

If you navigate from one component to the same component Angular won't create and initialise this component again (so ngOnInit isn't called again). In those cases you should work with Observables that emit a new value when the Component should display new data.

```ts
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.paramMap.pipe(
    tap(params => this.id = params.get("id")),
    switchMap(params => this.service.categories(params.get("id"), this.from, this.to))
  ).subscribe(res => {
    if (res['status'] == 1) {
      this.ayurvedic = res['data'];
      console.log(this.ayurvedic);
    }
  });
}
```